# Prove there exists a $c$ such that $-f'(c)=\frac{f(c)}c$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Let $f: \Bbb{R} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $[0,2]$ and differentiable on $(0,2)$.

$f(2)=0$.

Prove there exists a $c \in (0,2)$ such that $-f'(c)=\frac{f(c)}c$.

What I did:

1) From MVT: $\exists c_2 :f'(c_2)=\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2-0}=\frac{-f(0)}2$

As $-f'(c)=\frac{f(c)}c \iff -f'(c_2)=\frac{f(c_2)}{c_2}$

I can replace $f'(c_2)$ to get:

$\frac{f(0)}{2}=\frac{f(c_2)}{c_2}$ .

2) This last statement is equivalent to prove that:

$$
g(x)=xf(0)-2f(x)
$$

Has a root on $(0,2)$

As:
$g(0)=-2f(0)$ and $g(2)=2f(0)$, if $f(0)\neq0$ I can say that due to Rolle's theorem has a root, but what if $f(0)=0$?

Is my reasoning so far correct?

Comment: You may want to look at $x \mapsto x f(x)$. Meanwhile, I'm not sure what you in the second line of your 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

consider the function $g$ defined by $$g(x) = xf(x).  $$ we have $g(0) = g(2) = 0.$ by rolle's theorem, you have $$g'(c) = 0 \to cf'(c) + f(c) = 0 \to -f'(c) = \frac{f(c)}{c}$$ for some $0 < c < 2.$